# Select in materialize with type in search option

Tags: jquery, material-design, materialized-views

I have a simple materialize select field similar to:

```
<label>Browser Select</label>
<select class="browser-default">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Car</option>
  <option value="2">Bike</option>
  <option value="3">Plane</option>
</select>
```

I need to add a search option to this select as I have a lot of options under select.

Comment: I'm make this for my project: https://jsfiddle.net/xv0p06d3/  would it be this ?

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do is have the DB data , organize data list with PHP and AJAX to make a append at the select; like this:

```
   <?php
 include ("conex.php");


$resultado2 = $mysqli->query('Select curso.curso_id, curso.curso_nombre
From curso');


while($row4 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<option value="'.$row4['curso_id'].'">'.$row4['curso_nombre'].'</option>';    

}
?>
```

AJAX:

```
$.post("../scripts/cargar_cursos_paraAdmin.php", function(data, status){
       $("#loCursos").append(data);
        //console.log("cursos"+status);
    });
```

Comment: Does not answer question